# Using grep in conditional statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I'm still very new to scripting in bash, and just trying a few what I thought would be basic things. I want to run DDNS that updates from the my server running Ubuntu 14.04.

Borrowing some code from dnsimple, this is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGIN="email"
TOKEN="token"
DOMAIN_ID="domain"
RECORD_ID="record"
IP=`curl -s http://icanhazip.com/`

OUTPUT=`
curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "X-DNSimple-Domain-Token: $TOKEN" \
     -X "PUT" \
     -i "https://api.dnsimple.com/v1/domains/$DOMAIN_ID/records/$RECORD_ID" \
     -d "{\"record\":{\"content\":\"$IP\"}}"`

if ! echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "(Status:\s200)"; then

echo "match"

$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -oP '(?<="message":")(.[^"]*)' >> /home/ddns/ddns.log)
$(echo "$OUTPUT"| grep -P '(Status:\s[0-9]{3}\s)' >> /home/ddns/ddns.log)

fi
```

The idea is that it runs every 5 minutes, which I have working using a cronjob. I then want to check the output of the curl to see if the status is "200" or other. If it is something else, then I want to save the output to a file.

What I can't get working is the `if` statement. As I understand it, the `-q` on the `grep` command will provide an exit code for the `if` statement. However I can't seem to get it work. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Does your script work if you remove the `if` check and always echo to the log file?  [dnssimple](https://developer.dnsimple.com/ddns/) shows a `$LOGIN` before `$TOKEN`, but you're missing that.  Maybe that's causing things to fail?

Comment: I've slightly modified it. I'm using a `DNSimple-Domain-Token` which doesn't need the `LOGIN` variable.

Comment: if i were you, i'd run this only when the internet network interface goes up rather than every 5 minutes from cron.  or, at least, cache "$IP" in a file somewhere (perhaps `/var/tmp/icanhazip`) and if it hasn't changed since the last run, `exit 0` before doing anything else.  you don't need to update your DDNS entry every 5 minutes, only when your IP address changes.

Comment: Good idea - I will work on adding that.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You're almost there. Just omit the exclamation mark:

```
OUTPUT='blah blah (Status: 200)'
if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "(Status:\s200)"; then
    echo "MATCH"
fi
```

Result:

```
MATCH
```

The `if` condition is fulfilled if grep returns with exit code 0 (which means a match). The `!` exclamation mark will negate this.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work, but when I remove the `echo` it works for me. `if ! php -m | grep -q trader; then echo 'not existent'; fi`

Comment: @Jelmer Your code has very little in common with the code in the question, so you can't expect the answer's code to work as is, without editing.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're already using bash, you could keep it internal to bash:

```
if [[ $OUTPUT =~ (Status:[[:space:]]200) ]]; then
  echo match
fi
```

Sample runs:

```
OUTPUT='something bogus'
[[ $OUTPUT =~ (Status:[[:space:]]200) ]] && echo match


OUTPUT='something good (Status: 200)'
[[ $OUTPUT =~ (Status:[[:space:]]200) ]] && echo match
match
```

Answer (score 8):

This is **not an answer** to your question, but few suggestions from a fellow scripter:

- Use `$()` instead of backticks, don't use them both
- Indent conditional `if` statements
- Remove unnecessary usage of `$()`

Consistentecy and simple rules will help you debug and maintain scripts in a long run ...

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGIN="email"
TOKEN="token"
DOMAIN_ID="domain"
RECORD_ID="record"
IP=$(curl -s http://icanhazip.com/)

OUTPUT=$(
curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-DNSimple-Domain-Token: $TOKEN" \
    -X "PUT" \
    -i "https://api.dnsimple.com/v1/domains/$DOMAIN_ID/records/$RECORD_ID" \
    -d "{\"record\":{\"content\":\"$IP\"}}"
)

if ! echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "(Status:\s200)"; then
    echo "match"
    echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -oP '(?<="message":")(.[^"]*)' >> /home/ddns/ddns.log
    echo "$OUTPUT"| grep -P '(Status:\s[0-9]{3}\s)' >> /home/ddns/ddns.log
fi
```

Comment: Why not use backticks?